I am looking to reference a Table Column instead of a worksheet column
I have the following code to monitor specific cells for a change.  The code references target.column but I would rather use column names so the code doesn't break if columns are added to the table.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 6 Then
          Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 15) = Format(Now(), "mmmm d, yyyy at h:mm:ss")
    End If
    If Target.Column = 8 Then
          Target.Worksheet.Cells(Target.Row, 15) = Format(Now(), "mmmm d, yyyy at h:mm:ss")
    End If
End Sub

My table is "AV_Database"
Column 6 is "DLR"
Column 8 is "MSRP"
Column 15 is "Last Price Update"
The code works but gets broken when I insert columns into the table or change the order.  I would like to make this more robust by referencing column names.
Bonus question, I have another cell I'd like to monitor to trigger the timestamp but the code above doesn't work for it.  I believe it is because the cell is a formula dictated by other cells and not a value.  Is it possible to make that work as well?  This would be column 13 or "$ DLR CDN".
Thanks in advance for all your help.

Microsoft documentation:

ListObject.HeaderRowRange property (Excel)


ListObject.DataBodyRange property (Excel)


Application.Intersect method (Excel)


Range.ListObject property (Excel)

Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' The list of headers on trigger Cols, modify as needed
    Const KEY_COL = "DLR|MSRP|$ DLR CDN"
    Const UPDATE_COL = "Last Price Update"
    Const TAB_NAME = "AV_Database"
    With Target
        ' validate changed cell is single
        If .CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
        ' check change is a table (ListObject)
        Dim oTab As ListObject: Set oTab = .ListObject
        If oTab Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        ' check table name
        If UCase(oTab.Name) <> UCase(TAB_NAME) Then Exit Sub
        ' check change is not on table header
        Dim r As Range: Set r = Application.Intersect(oTab.HeaderRowRange, .Cells)
        If Not r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        ' get the header of changed column
        Set r = Application.Intersect(oTab.HeaderRowRange, .EntireColumn)
        ' check the change is on trigger cols
        If InStr(1, KEY_COL, r.Value) > 0 Then
            Dim updateCell As Range, iCol
            ' get the index of changed col
            iCol = Application.Match(UPDATE_COL, oTab.HeaderRowRange, 0)
            If IsError(iCol) Then Exit Sub
            ' update the cell with timestampe
            Set updateCell = Application.Intersect(oTab.ListColumns(iCol).Range, .EntireRow)
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            updateCell.Value = Format(Now(), "mmmm d, yyyy at h:mm:ss")
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub



